# Adding multiple if statements together

Tags: excel

I'm making a spreadsheet with different books people have to read and when the person gets finished reading the books they will mark and x and the box. So I have a formula for the following book columns E3,G3,I3and K3 which is COUNTIF(B3:L3,"X")*20. Can I add this formual to another so that N3 and O3 are worth 2.5?

Answer (score 2):

You can work with a nested `IF`, but this may soon become complicated.

In this case, I usually work with a hidden column containing the 'weight' of the column to be marked: say that column A contains the marker for volume A, then column B would contain 20%, and C would contain `=IF( A <> "", B, 0 );`

Then the `sum` column would contain `=SUM(C,F,I);`.

(example: [some google doc I made](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tGuNPvBdiBA_Nni36Jf9j3A&output=xls))

Comment: +1: The way to go, if you can't use a range or have different weights.

Answer (score 1):

You can cascade them:

```
=IF( A1="x", 10, IF( A2="X", 20, 0 )
```

Have a look at [COUNTIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php) though, if every `X` adds the same value:

```
=COUNTIF( A1:A20, "X" )
```

Comment: ok so it will add the 4 boxes together to equal 60. cause there are 4 boxes that equal 20

Comment: COUNTIFS(E3,G3,I3,K3="x","20","0") i typed this in and it gave me an error

Comment: I want to be like if e3 has an x in it then adds 20 to the total if g3 has an x in it to add another 20 to the total and if I3 has an x in it to adds another 20 to the total and if k3 has an x in it to adds another 20 to the total. so once the person is done it will be 60% of the volumns done

Comment: Sorry, `COUNTIF` only supports ranges, not single cells. The other answers provided seem to be better for your problem. BTW: Why does `20+20+20+20` result in `80`?

Comment: sorry i meant to say 80. so how do i put a hidden value to cells so they are calculated at the total column when x is entered

Comment: @Megan: What happened to `F3`, `H3` and `J3`?

Comment: those dont have a value on the cells i wrote above

Comment: correction- those dont have a value only the cells i wrote above have a value

Comment: @Megan: So as long as `F3`, `H3` and `J3` do not contain "X", `COUNTIF` will not count them. You can safely use a range (e.g. `=COUNTIF(B3:L3, "X")*20`)

Comment: Ok and if M3 and N3 equal 2.5 how do i add them to the total in the equation

Comment: @Megan: Maybe you should update your question to display all requirements you want.

Comment: @Megan: Yes, use multiple `SUM`. Edit your question first.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUMIF`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://x48.xanga.com/4d2f734165333263230876/b209830068.png))</sub>

(result should be 76%)

---

Use `COUNTIF` if the value is fixed.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://x88.xanga.com/5f28520416c49263231220/b209830327.png))</sub>

Comment: I want to be like if e3 has an x in it then adds 20 to the total if g3 has an x in it to add another 20 to the total and if I3 has an x in it to adds another 20 to the total and if k3 has an x in it to adds another 20 to the total. so once the person is done it will be 80% of the volumns done

Comment: @Megan: If it's a fixed 20 then use `=0.20 * COUNTIF(B2:F2, "X")`

Comment: @Megan: Also, "Column" or "Volume", there no such a word as "Volumn".

Comment: ok you get what i mean. Ok so do i input the formula into each individual box to add a values at the end or do i add the formula into the total box to tell it to put values to the "x"'s and add them

Comment: @Megan: Just put it in the totals (1 cell). `SUMIF` (and `COUNTIF`) updates automatically as the user put the "X".

Comment: ok so can u give me an example if E3 and G3 are marked with an "x" how it would equal 40

Comment: @Megan: See update. (And you really should read the Excel help file.)

Comment: i dont work with excel very much. just a one time question thats y im posting on here